# How to count words in a textbox separated by commas? (JavaScript / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For Example:

textbox value: word1,word2 
the function should return count = 2

textbox value: This is another word, words 
the function should return count = 2

textbox value: word1, word2, word3, 
the function should return count = 3

The function should count the words in a textbox split with commas.

Previously, I used length but now I need to count words instead of characters.

Comment: `value.split(',').length` should do it

Comment: You might consider doing a little research, making an attempt, and letting us know what you tried and what specifically goes wrong. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import jQuery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use the .split function

```js
$(function(){
    var word = "word1, word2, word3";
    var words = word.split(', ')
    console.log(words.length) // will return 3
  
})
```

Comment: that's great its working, but one thing, whenever I put a comma, it returns count+
for example: "word1", => returns 2 while I didn't write a second word yet, I want that when I write second word it should count